# Grouping objects contiguously by property, with exceptions in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of items like this in C#:

```
public class BlockListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<BlockListItem> items = new List<BlockListItem>
{
    new() { Id = 1, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 2, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 3, Alias = "B", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 4, Alias = "C", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 5, Alias = "C", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 6, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" },
    new() { Id = 7, Alias = "A", Theme = "Blue" },
};
```

I'd like to group these items in sequence by the Theme value. However, certain items should be ungroupable based on their Alias. The ungroupable aliases are supplied as a string array like this:

```
var ungroupableAliases = new[] { "C" };
```

The result I'm looking for would be something like this (pseudo values, just to demonstrate, with groups separated by dashed lines):

```
--------------------------------------
{ Id = 1, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" }
{ Id = 2, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" }
{ Id = 3, Alias = "B", Theme = "Red" }
--------------------------------------
{ Id = 4, Alias = "C", Theme = "Red" }
--------------------------------------
{ Id = 5, Alias = "C", Theme = "Red" }
--------------------------------------
{ Id = 6, Alias = "A", Theme = "Red" }
--------------------------------------
{ Id = 7, Alias = "A", Theme = "Blue" }
```

- Items 1-3 are grouped because they all have the Red theme.
- Item 4 is in its own group because it has an alias of C.
- Item 5 is in its own group because it has an alias of C.
- Item 6 is in its own group because it can't be grouped with the preceding item because the preceding item is ungroupable.
- Item 7 is in its own group because it has a different theme to the preceding item.

I have the following method which almost works:

```
private static List<List<BlockListItem>> GroupItems(IEnumerable<BlockListItem> items, string[] ungroupableAliases)
{
    if (items == null || !items.Any())
    {
        return new List<List<BlockListItem>>();
    }

    var itemGroups = new List<List<BlockListItem>>();
    var currentItemGroup = new List<BlockListItem> { items.First() };

    foreach (var item in items.Skip(1))
    {
        var itemIsGroupable = item.Theme == currentItemGroup.First().Theme && !ungroupableAliases.Contains(item.Alias);

        if (!itemIsGroupable)
        {
            itemGroups.Add(currentItemGroup.ToList());
            currentItemGroup = new List<BlockListItem>(); // Create a new group for ungroupable items.
        }

        currentItemGroup.Add(item);
    }

    itemGroups.Add(currentItemGroup.ToList());

    return itemGroups;
}
```

However, it's still grouping item 6 with item 5. Item 5 should be ungroupable.

Could anyone please advise how to modify this so that the grouping is as desired?

There's a [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ajxpiv).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest extracting a *special case* when an item has `Alias` which is in `ungroupableAliases`, when we should

- close the current `group`
- add an `item` as a group with the single element
- start a new `group`

i.e. (and let it be Linq free)

```
private static List<List<BlockListItem>> GroupItems(IEnumerable<BlockListItem> items, 
                                                    string[] ungroupableAliases) {
  List<List<BlockListItem>> result = new();
 
  List<BlockListItem> group = null;

  foreach (var item in items ?? Array.Empty<BlockListItem>()) {
    if (ungroupableAliases.Contains(item.Alias)) {
      if (group != null)  
        result.Add(group); 

      result.Add(new List<BlockListItem>() {item});

      group = null; 
    }
    else if (group != null && group[0].Theme == item.Theme)
      group.Add(item);
    else {
      if (group != null)  
        result.Add(group); 

      group = new List<BlockListItem>() {item};
    }
  }

  if (group != null)  
    result.Add(group);

  return result;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WfFCqx)